# emscripten std::chrono::system_clock::now() in C++ vs Date.now() in javascript

Tags: webassembly, emscripten, embind

When compiled with emscripten, is it safe to compare `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` in C++ and `Date.now()` in JS to calculate time differences?

Do they use the same clocks under the hood?

I need pretty accurate time comparisons down to the milli-second, hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

They do use the same clock under the hood, but probably at different precisions.

[`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) counts milliseconds since 1970-01-01 UTC excluding leap seconds.

[`std::chrono::system_clock::now()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#overview-1) counts "ticks" since 1970-01-01 UTC excluding leap seconds<sup>1</sup>, where "ticks" is a compile time fraction of a second that is described by `std::chrono::system_clock::period::num/std::chrono::system_clock::period::den`.  This expression is an integral numerator / integral denominator which indicates what fraction of a second the tick represents.  In practice the numerator is always 1, and the denominator is:

- On macOS: 1,000,000, so microseconds.
- On Windows: 10,000,000, so tenths of a microsecond.
- On Linux: 1,000,000,000, so nanoseconds.

You can truncate the C++ `system_clock::now()` with: `std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now())` and then it is a count of milliseconds.

`time_point_cast` truncates towards zero.  In C++17 you can also use `round`, `floor` or `ceil` in place of `time_point_cast` to achieve different rounding modes in the truncation from the finer precision to milliseconds.

---

<sup>1</sup> In C++11/14/17 the epoch of `system_clock` was unspecified.  But in practice every implementation used the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) epoch.  In C++20 this existing practice was standardized.